# Flutter Appbar doesn't fill up space above battery and time status bar

Tags: flutter, dart

My appbar code is currently encountering an issue where the appbar doesn't extend to fill the space behind the battery status bar and the time display. I'm unsure how to resolve this problem without disrupting the automatic hiding of the appbar when scrolling down. (I can't utilize SliverAppBar for auto-hide functionality due to heavy reliance on controllers in my code for pagination loading actions, ...) If you have any suggestions for addressing this matter, I would greatly appreciate your input. Thank you!

[image]

Here is my code:

```
return Scaffold(
      key: _key,
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(45),
        child: AnimatedContainer(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 150),
            height: _showAppbar ? 45 : 0,
            child: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: const Color(0xfffafafa).withAlpha(200),
              elevation: 0,
              flexibleSpace: ClipRect(
                child: BackdropFilter(
                  filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10, sigmaY: 10),
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              title: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      InkWell(
                          onTap: () => _key.currentState!.openDrawer(),
                          child: const AvatarWidget(
                            size: 36,
                          )),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              const Text(
                                'Xin chào,',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontFamily: 'AvertaStdCY-Light',
                                  fontSize: 15,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    shortName,
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 19,
                                      fontFamily: "Montserrat-Bold",
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  if (userCurrent.verified == true)
                                    Image.asset(
                                      "assets/images/verified.png",
                                      height: 18,
                                    ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )),
      ),
```

Comment: wrap the Scaffold() widget with the SafeArea() widget !!

Comment: @OMiShah i wrapped the Scaffold() widget with the SafeArea() but still got the above problem 